# Controlling execution of WooCommerce javascript functions

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce

What's the correct way of removing or applying conditions to WooCommerce JavaScript functions?

In particular, I'd like to stop all stock messages.  If I could stop messages based on classes or properties available in the DOM, even better.

By default when a variation stock falls to zero, WooCommerce removes all of the descendants of this element:

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation single_variation"></div>
```

and inserts this element:

```
<p>Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.</p>
```

I deleted the p element text in the template file: variation.php, so now WooCommerce inserts an empty p element.

It looks like this behavior is initiated in this js file: add-to-cart-variation.js

What's the correct way of suppressing the removal and insertion of elements in the div.single_variation, preferably based on a css class assigned to one of these elements or the value of an attribute assigned to the form.cart ancestor element?

Answer (score 0):

To remove *"Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination."* text, you can simply use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_script_data', 'remove_variation_unavailable_text_js', 10, 2 ); 
function remove_variation_unavailable_text_js( $params, $handle )  {
    if( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' === $handle ) {
        $params['i18n_unavailable_text'] = '';
    }
    return $params;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

All those variation *stock messages* are handled by [WC_Frontend_Scripts Class](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.3/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-frontend-scripts.php#L583-L593), in here:

```php
// From line 583 to line 593
case 'wc-add-to-cart-variation':
    // We also need the wp.template for this script :).
    wc_get_template( 'single-product/add-to-cart/variation.php' );

    $params = array(
        'wc_ajax_url'                      => WC_AJAX::get_endpoint( '%%endpoint%%' ),
        'i18n_no_matching_variations_text' => esc_attr__( 'Sorry, no products matched your selection. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'i18n_make_a_selection_text'       => esc_attr__( 'Please select some product options before adding this product to your cart.', 'woocommerce' ),
        'i18n_unavailable_text'            => esc_attr__( 'Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ),
    );
    break;
```

so there is no need to make changes to `variation.php` template file.

Comment: Thanks.  The parameter 'i18n_unavailable_text' of the 'woocommerce_get_script_data' filter doesn't replace the text generated by this line in the variation.php template: <p><?php esc_html_e( 'Sorry, this product is unavailable. Please choose a different combination.', 'woocommerce' ); ?></p>

Comment: I was able to suppress this message by replacing this line with the contents of the element <script type="text/template" id="tmpl-variation-template"> in a custom variation.php template.  I'm wondering if I'm missing a filter or a parameter of the 'woocommerce_get_script_data' that will replace this line of code without a custom template.